# nodejs regex bug

Tags: node.js

I have a regular expression `/\d*?,\d*?,.*?\./`
I tested it on a string `'Bub,160,20221219_120814672_iOS.png'`
I expected a `false`, but it reported `true`.
The version of Node.Js is v18.16.1
I think it is a bug of nodejs. What do you think?

Comment: Could you provide the code please?

Comment: Your regex is not anchored, it matches a fragment of the input string (to be more specific, it matches `,160,20221219_120814672_iOS.`). Anchor the regex to the beginning and end of the string (`/^\d*?,\d*?,.*?\.$/`) if you want it to match the entire input.

Comment: Test your regular expressions on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/axFmVM/1) to see how they match.

Comment: If you think you find a bug (without needing to do complicated things to show it) in some software which is widely used, the chances are that the bug is in *your* code.

Comment: Thanks to axiac. You solved my question.